# Convert column 'day' to datetime with year specification

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a dataframe that includes a column of day numbers for which the year is known:

```
print (df)
        year  day  time  
0       2012  227   800
15      2012  227   815
30      2012  227   830
...     ...   ...   ...
194250  2013  226  1645
194265  2013  226  1700
```

I have attempted to convert the day numbers to datetime `%m-%d` using:

```
import pandas as pd    
df['day'] = pd.to_datetime(df['day'], format='%j').dt.strftime('%m-%d')
```

which gives:

```
        year    day  time
0       2012  08-15   800
15      2012  08-15   815
30      2012  08-15   830
...     ...   ...     ...
194250  2013  08-14  1645
194265  2013  08-14  1700
```

but this conversion is incorrect because the 227th day of 2012 is August 14th (08-14). I believe this error is down to the lack of year specification in the conversion.

How can I specify the year in the conversion to get a) `%Y-%m-%d` ; b) `%m-%d` ; c)`%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M` from the dataframe I have?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try converting `year` into datetime type and `day` into timedelta type, remember to offset the date:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['year'], format='%Y') + \
        pd.to_timedelta(df['day'] -1, unit='D')
```

Output:

```
0        2012-08-14
15       2012-08-14
30       2012-08-14
194250   2013-08-14
194265   2013-08-14
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Then extract the date-month with `strftime`:

```
df['day'] = dates.dt.strftime('%M-%D')
```

Comment: Quang Hoang your solution works for resolving the datetime issue for the whole df, but misses adding in the time info. MrFuppes's solution adds in the time info but I could only get it to work for one row, not the whole df. I merged both solutions: QH's to convert day->date, then MF's to add the time info. Thank you both very much. Sorry I cannot seem to @ anyone in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

you can convert to string and feed into `pd.to_datetime`, which you supply with the right parsing directive:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2012, 2012], 'day' : [227, 228], 'time': [800, 0]})

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.year.astype(str) + ' ' +
                                df.day.astype(str) + ' ' +
                                df.time.astype(str).str.zfill(4), 
                                format='%Y %j %H%M')

df['datetime']

0   2012-08-14 08:00:00
1   2012-08-15 00:00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Formatting to string is just a call to `strftime` via `dt` accessor, e.g.

```
df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')

0    2012-08-14T08:00
1    2012-08-15T00:00
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```

Comment: is the purpose of the zfill(4) to turn the times without a leading zero into times with four digits (ie incl leading zero) ? Combined with QH's code, your code gave all of the times correctly even without the zfill. Thank you!

Comment: @R_Dax exactly :) It didn't work when I tested with e.g. `0` for 00:00 hours (i.e. anything less than 3 digits), so I added the zfill.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Maybe it was fine for me in this specific case since my times all have at least 3 digits (that is (0)800 to 1700) but it will help in future cases with time formats of fewer than 3 digits. Thank you! :)